Breadcrumbs in NextJS
I want to add breadreumbs to my nextjs app. For now my idea is to split a path like /app/books/category/ and eventually uppercase first letter to make it look nicer. However, what is the recommended approach to map path to another string? For example instead of mapping category to Category, I'd like to use Book category. SHould I use simple mapping or there is an inbuilt functionality I could use?
